# Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]

Tags: ros

I'm using ros kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04

I'm trying to do run [this project](https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo) but not running inside a Docker container.

After, I had done

```
user@user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/gym-gazebo/gym_gazebo/envs/installation/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
user@user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/gym-gazebo/gym_gazebo/envs/installation$ bash setup_kinetic.bash
user@user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/gym-gazebo/gym_gazebo/envs/installation$ bash turtlebot_setup.bash
user@user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/gym-gazebo/examples/turtlebot$ python circuit2_turtlebot_lidar_qlearn.py
```

Then, it comes out the following error:

```
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/3ac6e572-28a3-11e8-9aba-142d27dccbb5/roslaunch-user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC-6853.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:37855/
ros_comm version 1.12.12


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.12

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6864]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:11311/

setting /run_id to 3ac6e572-28a3-11e8-9aba-142d27dccbb5
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6884]
started core service [/rosout]
Roscore launched!
Gazebo launched!
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/3ac6e572-28a3-11e8-9aba-142d27dccbb5/roslaunch-user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC-6908.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

while processing /home/user/gym-gazebo/gym_gazebo/envs/installation/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot_simulator/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/xacro/xacro --inorder '/home/user/gym-gazebo/gym_gazebo/envs/installation/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

And the kobuki.launch.xml :

```html
<launch>
  <arg name="base" />
  <arg name="stacks" />
  <arg name="3d_sensor" />
  <arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro'" />
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(arg urdf_file)" />
  <!-- Gazebo model spawner -->
  <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base" />
  <!-- Velocity muxer -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="mobile_base_nodelet_manager" args="manager" />
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="cmd_vel_mux" args="load yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager">
    <param name="yaml_cfg_file" value="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/param/mux.yaml" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel_mux/output" to="mobile_base/commands/velocity" />
  </node>
  <!-- Bumper/cliff to pointcloud (not working, as it needs sensors/core messages) -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/includes/kobuki/bumper2pc.launch.xml" />
</launch>
```

This is what I get after run `xacro --inorder /home/user/gym-gazebo/gym_gazebo/envs/installation/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro`

```
option --inorder not recognized
Usage: xacro.py [-o <output>] <input>
       xacro.py --deps       Prints dependencies
       xacro.py --includes   Only evalutes includes
```

I'm still new with ROS. Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried running the `xacro` command by hand to see what it says?

Comment: I had edited the question by adding the xacro command, Is there any problem?

Comment: Looks like your xacro version is not right. It doesn't recognize the `--inorder` option, but [according to wiki.ros.org](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro) that option should be available in ros Jade and newer. Can you check if all your packages are really up-to-date ros Kinetic packages?

Comment: How do i check whether all my package is up to date?

Comment: Run `rosversion xacro`. Judging by the [github xacro repo](https://github.com/ros/xacro/blob/kinetic-devel/package.xml), you should be seeing version 1.11.2.

Comment: You could also try to simply remove the `--inorder` option from your launch XML and see if that works.

Comment: when i run `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-xacro`, it show `ros-kinetic-xacro is already the newest version (1.11.2-0xenial-20180222-225948-0800).`. After that, i run `rosversion xacro` it say 1.9.5. umm... strange

Comment: But i try to remove `--inorder` in launch XML, the problem is gone. Thank for help.

Comment: You may want to contact the xacro people directly. According to their own docs, `--inorder` _should_ be available in their version. Maybe it's a bug on their part. But I'm glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Error Your Getting From Xacro Is Actually From A `--inorder` tag Which Is Mostly Used In ROS Indigo(To My best of knowledge) And I Don't Think U Need It In ROS Kinetic (But I'm Not Sure Cause I'm Still On Indigo Myself) I Suggest U Try It Without The `--inorder` Argument And If U ran Into Problems Try Replacing it With `-i` As Said In The xacro Changelog In Their [Github](https://github.com/ros/xacro/blob/kinetic-devel/CHANGELOG.rst)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

The above command solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error says cannot load command parameter [robot_description] from

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/xacro/xacro --inorder '/home/user/gym-gazebo/gym_gazebo/envs/installation/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot/turtlebot_description/robots/kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro'
```

The problem you're seeing is because of the single quote characters in the command line of the `xacro file`. Line 6 is where param name is given as `robot description`, and it isnt getting loaded as `urdf` path hasn't been read properly in the previous line because of the single quotes. In order to load the file remove the single quotes in line 5.

Change line 5 which is

```
<arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder '$(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro'" />
```

to the following

```
<arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro" />
```

The `xml` file should look like

```
<launch>
<arg name="base" />
<arg name="stacks" />
<arg name="3d_sensor" />
<arg name="urdf_file" default="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot_description)/robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro" />
<param name="robot_description" command="$(arg urdf_file)" />
<!-- Gazebo model spawner -->
<node name="spawn_turtlebot_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base" />
<!-- Velocity muxer -->
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="mobile_base_nodelet_manager" args="manager" />
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="cmd_vel_mux" args="load yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager">
  <param name="yaml_cfg_file" value="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/param/mux.yaml" />
  <remap from="cmd_vel_mux/output" to="mobile_base/commands/velocity" />
</node>
<!-- Bumper/cliff to pointcloud (not working, as it needs sensors/core messages) -->
<include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/includes/kobuki/bumper2pc.launch.xml" />
</launch>
```